# Python recipe question: Use of **kwds instead of specific named argument in itertools recipe

Tags: python

The function definition below comes from the itertools recipes page
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

```
def random_product(*args, **kwds):
    "Random selection from itertools.product(*args, **kwds)"
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    return tuple(random.choice(pool) for pool in pools)
```

The function signature would seem to be more readable written with the "repeat" argument specified explicitly, e.g.

```
def random_product(*args, repeat=1)
```

But I'm guessing there is a reason why it is written using the general idiom.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383620/why-use-kwds-instead-of-a-specific-named-argument-in-a-function-definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, you cannot put a keyword argument after `*args`, that's a syntax error:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def random_product(*args, repeat=1):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def random_product(*args, repeat=1):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you put it *before* the positional catch-all, then it captures the first positional argument:

```
>>> def random_product(repeat=1, *args): return repeat, args
... 
>>> random_product('foo', 'bar')
('foo', ('bar',))
```

In Python 2 then, your only option is to capture arbitrary keyword arguments with `**kw` (since that only ever captures actual keyword arguments, not positional arguments), and extract `repeat` from that.

Python 3 adjusted what is supported; there any keyword arguments specified after the `*args` catch-all are allowed and are seen as keyword-only:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def random_product(*args, repeat=1):  return args, repeat
... 
>>> random_product('foo', 'bar')
(('foo', 'bar'), 1)
```